# Leaving internship early for full-time opportunity

Tags: software-industry, internship, hiring, fulltime

I am in the middle of my 1-year internship at the moment and I am quite satisfied. Although things are nice here, I have no interest in continuing here as full-time.

Considering that, I have been thinking where I will be working next, which means I have already started looking for work opportunities. I also marked my online profile as "open".

I have been offered with some really good positions at great companies.

Since my internship won't be ending any time sooner, I told the first recruiter, that I won't be available before the end date of my internship (5 months from now) and he was totally fine with it. So, we started scheduling our interviews.

A second recruiter has just approached me and he is not still aware that I am not currently available. This recruiter offers an outstanding position for which I am very interested in.

I am worried about whether my current unavailability will push away the second recruiter's opportunity.

The first opportunity is actually a program which is the reason it is time-flexible. The second one is a typical job opening which is certainly not going to be waiting 5 months for me.

**If the second opportunity is indeed an asap position and I get selected, should I abandon/end my internship and go work for them?**

The benefits of the second position comparing to my internship ones, are by far greater, so this makes me think: **Why continue working for an internship salary when I can get a big full-time salary right now?**

I know leaving my internship is not nice, but is it unprofessional or totally unacceptable? Is there a way to professionally quit my internship early?

*Additional information:*

Location is UK. Contract is for one year but through a recruitment organization which also provides the accommodation. So, if quitting the internship, I will have to resign both from the work company and the recruitment company as well.

Comment: Duplicate tagging is not accurate as my internship experience has been positive so far without any problems

Comment: Read the answers, don't just dismiss the question because it's not exactly what your asking. Read the answers.  There are a ton of questions on leaving internships. I'd suggest doing a search first.

Comment: I read the answers of your duplicate tag as well all the other "internship ending" related posts. The so far answers in this post are quite different than the duplicate's answers, which makes sense cause they regard totally different situations.

Comment: @ChrisE While the answers are useful IMO in this situation, this question is different enough to me to not be a duplicate.

Comment: Are you doing an internship because it's part of your educational program, or are you interning to gain more experience? One of my nephews had to intern to gain experience because his field was very competitive. In such case, I would jump on the possibility to get a job rather than staying an intern.

Comment: @EdwinLambregts I need to do a 6 month internship in order to graduate from my department. My internship agreement is a one-year one and since I am in the middle now, I have completed my mandatory university part. Thus, that's why I am questioning the purpose of the remaining 6 months, since I am already getting real far better job offers.

Comment: The time to question / challenge the remaining 6 months was before you signed the contract.

Comment: @Paparazzi At that time, a one year internship at this company was a big success for me. Now, after 6 months of working and developing my skills, the term "successful-prosperous position" for me, has been updated/redefined. I would't know I will be getting such good offers before I even finish my Internship period.

Comment: So what is good for you has changed.  Did you signed a 1 year contract?

Comment: Would you mind not using **bold** so much? It annoys at least one person considerably, and most people are perfectly able to zoom in on the important words in a sentence. ;)

Comment: @AnoE You are right, did not notice that till now.

Comment: You might want to add info about your location (just country is probably enough) and whether or not you signed a contract, as those aspects may affect folks' advice.

Comment: What does your contract say? In a lot of countries there are some minimum figures prescribed by law, and they may be increased by the contract. In Italy this time depends on the kind of job and duration of employement and can become as high as 6 months for a manager that has been working for 10+ years at a company.

Comment: @Bakuriu Starting-Ending dates, work objectives, compensation and my obligations (fulfil all internship requirements-don't know what 'all' means, follow codes etc.). Does not state what may happen if I fail to fulfil an obligation - I guess nothing?

Comment: Not unacceptable. In fact, I bet your supervisor would tell you to go for it. Just give 2 weeks and do your best to ensure that your leaving won't break anything. 

But really, read the contract. Contrary to what paparazzi is suggesting, you CAN break contracts, you just have to be willing to accept the consequences.

Comment: Usually it is a good thing to leave an internship, and find a real job.  Normally that is how things are meant to go.  I have had many interns over the years, and part of the internship is accepting that interns leave early.  I openly encouraged my, that I thought were ready,  to apply for jobs.  **Your region is different, and so are the rules.**

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Why continue working for an internship salary when I can get a big
>   full-time salary right now?

Only you can answer this question.  If you have nothing left to gain, consider accepting full time work and getting your career in gear.  If you have multiple job offers, *weigh the pros and cons of each* and make an informed decision.

> I know leaving my internship is not nice, but is it unprofessional or
>   totally unacceptable?

No it is not unprofessional, and it is not "mean" either.  What *would* make it unprofessional is if you left without giving some sort of notice to allow them to find someone to do your part.

> Is there a way to professionally quit my internship early?

Yes, give your manager a resignation letter **which includes when your last day will be**.  (Sending an email with this content is fine too)  The amount of notice will vary by location, in the US it is typically two or three weeks.

If you provide **notice**, and do you best to make the transition from you to the next person as **seamless** as possible, you will have done your part and can leave with your conscience clear.

Comment: One could say it is unprofessional to break a contract. If OP has an employment contract, which it seems is the case, then it could be considered unprofessional to break that contract. That said, the difference between a full time salary and internship salary are so substantial that it makes sense to do it.

Comment: All employment is a contract. They are not time- nor delivery-bound, so they will be "broken" at some point, because they have no natural end. They often have clauses to reflect this fact. (If this was a contractor situation with delivery-bounded contract, that's a different matter...)

Comment: I'd say its the very definition of professional. Give notice  just like a full-time employee would, if you're worried about it. Seriously, "amateur" is donating your time for little or no monetary benefit. Professional is getting paid.

Comment: @jdmichal Well, some employment contracts are time-bound, in the sense that the employee is expected to stay at the job for a certain amount of time. It's not uncommon in academia, at least; I'm not sure if there are other categories of jobs that commonly do this.

Comment: and you'll also have _2_ references for your next job interview after this new gig. Never burn bridges.

Comment: @jdmichal It's a 1-year internship so it has a natural end. I know at least one country (France) where the law technically does not give employees the right to resign from fixed-term contracts outside of a limited list of special situations (being hired elsewhere on a permanent contract is one of these exceptions, though). I wrote “technically” because it's difficult to enforce and your employer is not going to secure huge damages from a court if you just leave but contracts typically do not provide for a resignation.

Comment: @corsiKa At least in my legislation, quitting a job with giving notice is not *breaking* the contract, because how to quit with notice is written down in and thus part of the contract. Breaking would be to quit without notice (except in a few rare cases allowed by the law), and that could in fact incur a fine for contract violation.

Comment: @Relaxed Another exception allowing to resign from a fixed-term contract in France is a "mutual agreement between the parties", which in practice is not that difficult to get. Unless your role is critical for the company, no reasonable employer will force you to stay on a job you don't want anymore.

Comment: @JonasWielicki I'd agree with you, except OP stated that such terms are not in the contract. And if they aren't in the contract, the only outs he has are whatever unwritten terms exist, such as "provide safe working environment" etc.

Comment: @jdmichal Not all employment is contract. I've worked many (professional, engineering) jobs for which I signed no employment contract.

Comment: I would consider it unprofessional to *actively pursue* other employment opportunities when you're on contract for 1 year and there's nothing about the environment that is causing you to leave. If you serendipitously find another job that's a slightly different matter. 
Also you're likely displacing another intern by taking the position and then leaving early.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev That's not resigning. And “reasonable” is doing a lot of the work here.

Comment: @corsiKa If you were writing software in the US without an employment contract, then there was no IP / copyright transfer from you to the company. Which is obviously a huge issue.

Comment: You're making an invalid assumption. You can have an NDA without an employment contract. I've worked for DoD contractors and tech startups without an employment contract, but did have an NDA. (The one for the DoD was quite extensive, as you might imagine.)

Answer (score 15):

Other answers have covered this much better but quickly I'd like to reiterate that it's completely fine to move to a new position given you provide notice. Many people, particularly in the Software industry will take interviews while in employment and might hop between companies (especially start-ups).

What sticks out to me from your question is that no, you haven't been offered a position, to me it sounds like you've been offered an interview. Forgive me if I'm wrong about that but you should take the words of a recruiter with a pinch of salt - in my experience most recruiters aren't even worth that (a pinch of salt that is). I've known many budding developers that did all the right things coming out of education and had all the right qualifications (including industry experience like yourself), it still can take many interviews until an offer will stick.

I would have rather written this more concisely as a comment but I have no rep as I mostly lurk on SE.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right, I am still at the interviews-level but the reason I asked is that I want to know what will happen if these interviews evolve into offers.

Answer (score 11):

You should only remain at any given job if it makes sense for you to do so.

Even if your internship were a full time position, you're being offered more money, benefits, etc. Why would you walk away from that?

If your employer deemed it advantageous to fire you, I can assure you that they would do so with no second thoughts. Why would you hesitate to act in your own self interest under these circumstances?

Unless this internship is somehow a graduation requirement, do yourself a favor and go for the better, *full-time* position instead of sticking around to a worse paid, temporary one.

Answer (score 9):

An internship is not a real job.

Let that sink in for a second.

An internship is not a real job.

The reason you do an internship is to be more successful in obtaining a real job.

Leaving your internship for a real job then should be entirely ok. Because you're not doing a real job, the company shouldn't have any problems with it. You shouldn't even consider nice or not nice. Apparently the internship worked out so well that you got a real, better job before it was over.

Now I of-course know that many interns do real work. And that's companies being not-so-nice and hiring interns for real jobs and instead of paying them real salaries they pay intern salaries.

When you started your internship you signed a contract. There should be a notice period in your contract. Play by rules and stick to that notice period.

Answer (score 3):

A paid internship always comes with a contract, which should specify the notice period you have to respect. If the notice period is not specified, statutory minimum notice periods apply, which AFAIK is one week if you're employed for less than 2 years in UK. Make sure you respect this obligation, and nobody will call you unprofessional for leaving for a better opportunity.

Of course, the situation is a little different if this internship is a requirement to get a degree (typical for final-year students): you still can leave your internship on the same terms as above, but if you do, you don't get your degree.